# Listview adapter in a ViewPager in a fragment - How to get the Activity

Tags: listview, xamarin, android-viewpager, xamarin.android

I'm trying to build a music browser/player of the local files on the devices using a CursorLoader. I'm using Xamarin android, c#. I'm using a ViewPager which is within a Fragment (not FragmentActivity, since the fragment is part of a Navigation Drawer).

I'm having trouble with the listView.Adapter which is used to show the songs since I'm not able to get the Activity. When using this listview adapter directly in a activity it works fine (I'm able to see the list of songs), but when trying to use it in a ViewPager located which is using a PagerAdapter (all that within a Fragment). I'm not able to get the Activity in listView.Adapter = new SongsAdapter (**this**,cursor,songsList). Could you please guide me in order to be able to pass the activity to the adapter or let me know if I'm doing anything wrong in general which makes it not possible?

Thank you. Your help is appreciated :)

Julien

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.View;

using Android.Provider;
using Android.Database;
using Android.Net;


namespace project
{
    public class MyDeviceFragment : Fragment
    {
        private SlidingTabScrollView mSlidingTabScrollView;
        private ViewPager mViewPager;

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.slidingtabfragment, container, false);
        }

        public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var activity = Activity;
            mSlidingTabScrollView = view.FindViewById<SlidingTabScrollView>(Resource.Id.sliding_tabs);
            mViewPager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
            mViewPager.Adapter = new SamplePagerAdapter();

            mSlidingTabScrollView.ViewPager = mViewPager;
        }

        public class SamplePagerAdapter : PagerAdapter
        {
            List<string> items = new List<string>();

            public SamplePagerAdapter() : base()
            {
                items.Add("PLaylists");
                items.Add("Songs");
                items.Add("Albums");
                items.Add("Artists");
                items.Add("Genres");
            }

            public override int Count
            {
                get { return items.Count; }
            }

            public override bool IsViewFromObject(View view, Java.Lang.Object obj)
            {
                return view == obj;
            }

            public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
            {
                View view = null;

                switch (position) {
                case 1:
                    ListView listView;
                    view = LayoutInflater.From (container.Context).Inflate (Resource.Layout.testinglistactivity, container, false);
                    listView = view.FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.List);

                    List<Song> songsList;

                    var uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ExternalContentUri;
                    string[] projection = {
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.InterfaceConsts.AlbumId,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.InterfaceConsts.Title,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.InterfaceConsts.Artist,
                    };
                    var loader = new CursorLoader (container.Context, uri, projection, null, null, null);
                    var cursor = (ICursor)loader.LoadInBackground ();
                    songsList = new List<Song> ();
                    if (cursor.MoveToFirst ()) {
                        do {
                            songsList.Add (new Song {
                                Id = cursor.GetLong (cursor.GetColumnIndex (projection [0])),
                                AlbumId = cursor.GetString (cursor.GetColumnIndex (projection [1])),
                                Title = cursor.GetString (cursor.GetColumnIndex (projection [2])),
                                Artist = cursor.GetString (cursor.GetColumnIndex (projection [3]))
                            });
                        } while (cursor.MoveToNext ());
                    }

                    listView.Adapter = new SongsAdapter (this,cursor,songsList);//***********HERE is the issue*********************
                    break;
                default:
                    view = LayoutInflater.From (container.Context).Inflate (Resource.Layout.pager_item, container, false);
                    int pos = position + 1;
                    TextView txtTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.item_title);

                    txtTitle.Text = pos.ToString ();
                    break;
                }
                container.AddView (view);
                return view;
            }

            public string GetHeaderTitle (int position)
            {
                return items[position];
            }

            public override void DestroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Java.Lang.Object obj)
            {
                container.RemoveView((View)obj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by doing the following:

1. Passing the Activity as an argument in: 
   mViewPager.Adapter = new MyDeviceAdapter(Activity);
2. Adding *this.context* = context to the constructor of the SamplePager Adapter

   public class SamplePagerAdapter : PagerAdapter
       {
           Activity context;
           List items = new List();

   ```
       public SamplePagerAdapter(Activity context) : base()
       {
           this.context = context;
           items.Add("PLaylists");
           items.Add("Songs");
           items.Add("Albums");
           items.Add("Artists");
           items.Add("Genres");
       }
   ```

   ...
3. Optional(not sur if it was required): I did separate the SamplePagerAdapter in another file where I was able to use Android.App instead of Android.Support.V4.App;

Comment: I have had the same issue with some additional requirement ...
Your answer assist me a lot ...
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Declare that at the beginning: `ParentActivity mParentActivity;`
In your onCreate() add: `mParentActivity =(ParentActivity) Activity;`

Now you can use `mParentActivity` to access to your parent activity.
For your problem, now you will do:

```
listView.Adapter = new SongsAdapter (mParentActivity, cursor, songsList);
```

Comment: Hi Timothé, thank you for the quick reply. The OnCreate you mention is part of the MainActivity containing my fragment (MyDevice) or is it part of the fragment itself? Inside of the fragment I'm not able to declare a ParentActivity. In the containing activity I'm able to use "Parent" but it would refer to the parent of the activity. I just figured out I'm able to pass the Activity in the SamplePagerAdapter constructor: mViewPager.Adapter = new SamplePagerAdapter(Activity); However I'm not able to use it in the listview.adapter which is part of InstantiateItem. Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi Timothé, I was able to solve my issue, doing the steps detailed below. Thank you for your help. It's appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can add the context of the container, it will solve the problem:

```
 listView.Adapter = new SongsAdapter (container.Context,cursor,songsList);
```